# Pivot table where column names are based on row values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering how to make a pivot table that contains time series data where each column represents a different product. In general, the column names would be:

```
date  |  var1  |  var2  |  var3  |  (etc...)
```

For example, if we have the below data:

```
 date                 price        discount_rate          maturity_date
 9/15/2013            45           3                      2013
 9/15/2013            46           3                      2014
 9/16/2013            47           3                      2013
 9/16/2013            41           2                      2014
```

Then we would have three distinct products name following the naming convention

```
 *var*_*discount*_*rate_maturity_date*
```

each as it's own column heading, with the first column being the date. The first part of the name, *series*, would be hardcoded but the rest of the name should be built based on the values in the distinct records. For example, the data in the above table would be returned in the form:

```
 date                 series_3_2013  series_3_2014  series_3_2_2014
 9/15/2013            45             46             NA
 9/16/2013            47             NA             41
```

Is a query like this feasible to write in PostgreSQL? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: thanks for the formatting assist Luv!

Comment: This is only possible using Dynamic SQL.

Comment: See a blog on dynamic sql pivot- http://crispycrappy.blogspot.in/2013/12/dynamic-sql-pivot.html